# Keyboard shortcut to hide/show Explorer navigation

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

Does **Windows Explorer** in **Windows 7** have a keyboard shortcut that hides or shows the navigation pane?

It's pretty annoying each time to click *Organize|Layout|Navigation pane*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a keyboard shortcut (I just tried all the ctrl/alt + alphabet keys, and none of them opened the navigation pane)

Answer (score 25):

In Windows 8.1 (maybe Windows 8 & 7 too, one needs to verify this), you can add the *Navigation Pane* option to the *Quick Access Toolbar*.  You can then use the `Alt+{NumberKey}` shortcut followed by the `Enter` key to show/hide the *Navigation Pane*.

For example: in my case, the *Navigation Pane* icon is the third item in the *Quick Access Toolbar*, so I would press `Alt+3` and then `Enter` to turn the pane on/off.

This has improved my workflow tremendously. Hope it helps you too.

#### HowTo: Configure

1. open *Windows File Explorer*
2. right-click *View* tab
3. right-click *Navigation Pane* toolbar button
4. click *Add to Quick Access Toolbar* menu item

#### Screen Shots

[image: Screen shot: right-click on *Navigation Pane* button]

**Figure1:** Right-Click Menu

[image: Quick Access with Navigation Pane button]

**Figure2:** *Quick Access Toolbar* with *Navigation Pane*

#### Related Notes

With respect to the *Quick Access Toolbar*, it is important to note that:

- Shortcuts are assigned left to right. For example, with reference to Figure2:

  - `Alt+1` = show properties
  - `Alt+2` = create new folder
  - `Alt+3` = show/hide *Navigation Pane*
- Shortcuts only work with the number keys at the top of a QWERTY keyboard.  They do not work with the number pad number keys.

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have a "Quick Access Toolbar".

Comment: I liked this answer, and I hope this illustration make it easier for people to understand what you are suggesting:  [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/F5RMies.png)

Comment: Works great in windows 10

Comment: For those who would like to use this solution in Windows 11, you can get it to work by restoring the Windows Explorer ribbon interface + Quick Access Toolbar in the UI by installing the program [StartAllBack](https://www.startallback.com). Open the StartAllBack options, select the "Explorer" tab, and enable the setting labeled "Win10 Ribbon UI". Close any open explorer windows and reopen a new explorer window to use the restored ribbon UI featured in @SMing's answer.

Answer (score 22):

Here is how I do it:

1) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (puts the focus in the Address bar, so works wherever it was before)

2) <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>

3) <kbd>Space</kbd>

4) <kbd>L</kbd>

5) <kbd>N</kbd>

This is optimized for speed of typing; you can save a <kbd>Tab</kbd> if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to put the focus in the search box instead.

If you've just opened the window, three presses of <kbd>Tab</kbd> will get you to the Organize button in step 3.

Answer (score 8):

here is a autohotkey script

Win+A toggles the navi pane

```
/*
Author:  
Date:    
Contact: 
*/

#NoTrayIcon
#Persistent
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance, Force

#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
#a::
Send !d{tab}{tab}{enter}ln
```

Comment: Nice! Using  `Send ^e{tab}{enter}ln` (CTRL+E, TAB ENTER instead of ALT+D TAB TAB ENTER) is slightly faster I've also bound it to ALT+N so I can use it with ALT+P `!n::` for toggling the preview pane without removing my finger from ALT.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I do it:

1) <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

2) <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

3) <kbd>↓</kbd>

4) <kbd>L</kbd>

5) <kbd>N</kbd>

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1) and 2) should probably be "shift+tab until you see a bounding box around 'organize'". tab & Shift+tab will cycle through all fields/controls/buttons on any/most windows dialogs...

Comment: This only works if the keyboard focus happens to be in the Explorer window. stevek_mcc’s answer is better because it starts from an absolute location instead of a relative one.

Answer (score 5):

I can toggle the preview pane in Windows 10 by typing (with the Explorer window focussed): <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note that Alt is a separate keypress to go into the mode where you navigate the ribbon by keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to record an action and script it. you and use autohotkey to execute that script with a keyboard shortcut. http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: I have used AutoHotKey before. Could you comment on how to record  actions runnable by AutoHotKey?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a macro in PhraseExpress (freely available [here](http://www.phraseexpress.com/download.htm)):

```
{#shift {#tab}}{#sleep 500}{#shift {#tab}}{#sleep 500}{#down}{#sleep 500}l{#sleep 500}n
```

Note: `sleep 500` makes it more stable.

Comment: where does the focus need to be when you run it?   The 1st time it ran it was ok but not it keeps trying to do a search.

Comment: Figured it out looking at the other answers.  Alt+D puts the focus in the correct location.    My final short cut: {#ALT -chars D}{#TAB}{#sleep 100}{#TAB}{#sleep 100}{#DOWN}{#sleep 100}{#SHIFT -chars l}{#sleep 100}{#SHIFT -chars n}   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but you can hide the navigation pane in one folder, and apply this setting for all folders. You will now have to manually enable the navigation pane each time you want to use it.

Here's how:

1. Open Folder Options via the Tools menu (<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>)
2. Select "View" tab
3. Press "Apply to Folders"

Comment: It's not about how to hide the pane permanently, rather I'd like to have an option to hide **and** show it using a key shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any keyboard shortcuts (apart from [OGR's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/41979/keyboard-shortcut-to-hide-show-explorer-navigation/270097#270097)), but there is a plugin which adds a Navigation Pane button to the Windows Explorer bar, which at least makes it quicker to toggle.

[image: NavPane button]

Details here: [Toggle the Navigation Pane with a Button in Windows Explorer](http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7customization/toggle-navigation-pane-button-windows-explorer/)

Answer (score 1):

Very good thread.  I wanted a folder with just icons that allows me to launch programs or folder locations of interest.  I think I'm there.  Here are keys:

1. Under folder options, view tab, click "Restore previous folder windows at logon"

   - so once I have folder set up the way I want, I just leave open when I logoff and it gets restored on next logon.  Thus, I turn off navigation panel and it comes back with it off.
2. To launch new folders in separate window (and just new ones), in shortcut target use the following:

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /n,/e, "Path to folder you want to start-in"
   ```

   So, if I want to open a explorer in the D: drive I use

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /n,/e, D:\
   ```

Now I set-up all the shortcuts in my key folder this way and they launch in a separate window, yet all other times when I double click on folder location they don't create separate window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not very well thought out on Microsoft's behalf.

If I have a folder on my desktop which contains JUST shortcut to programs that do say "audio" work. When I open the folder I just want to see icons, not the navigation pane.

If I make it vanish for that folder, then the next time I open explorer (say to look at my PC folder structure) it's gone from there also.

Windows 7 should remember whether or not the navigation pane was enabled on a "per folder" basis, or AT THE VERY LEAST, provide a quick shortcut key to display or hide it.

Piss poor if you ask me.

The navigation pane takes up a lot of space, and people who like their folders and work areas looking "just right" won't be very please at this omission. In this respect, the old explorer worked a lot better. (Even if it did forget the layout for ALL of your folders from time to time!). This one doesn't even have options to remember your folder layout with respect to the navigation pane. Probably why M$ couldn't be bothered to fix the original problem with it, electing to just ommit it from future versions instead.

Comment: I don't have Windows 7 yet, but Vista it did not save my folder settings until I disabled UAC. Do you have UAC enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ctrl+F which will open the pane and then switch to navigation tab, but creating a macro sounds easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to the question about Windows 7 but in Windows 10:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Toggle on/off:

Like the 1st method but we go one step further and add the actual toggle option to the quick-access toolbar and not the actual menu button, so all that is needed is a simple left-click of the mouse button:

-> Select the drop-down-arrow to list the options under "Navigation Pane"
-> right-click "Navigation Pane"
-> Add to quick-access toolbar

Voilla!

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Comment: Avoid posting wrong answers: the question was about Windows 7, which didn't have a quick access tool toolbar.