# Hotkey to show/hide left-hand `treeview` of Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Currently to toggle the `treeview` on the left-hand side of Windows Explorer we can use: **Organize - Layout - Navigation Pane** as below screenshot.

I do this very very often and want to toggle quickly by a hotkey. Please share if you know how to.
[image]

Answer (score 11):

Here is an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script. <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> toggles the navigation pane.

```
/*
Author:  
Date:    
Contact: 
*/

#NoTrayIcon
#Persistent
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance, Force

#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
#a::
Send !d{tab}{tab}{enter}ln
```

Answer (score 3):

This thread might be useful:
[Keyboard shortcut to hide/show Explorer navigation](https://superuser.com/questions/41979/keyboard-shortcut-to-hide-show-explorer-navigation)

According to the thread, there are no hotkeys to hide/show the navigation pane, but you can use <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> to get most of the way there.  Another poster suggests using a utility such as [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to create a script that you can assign to a custom hotkey.

Comment: Care to explain what the link says?

Comment: The link says it is impossible as I have read :)

Answer (score 3):

I provide a solution for Windows 8 here.

In file browser, first press <kbd>Alt</kbd>(do not hold for combination key). 
Then press <kbd>V</kbd>, and <kbd>N</kbd>.
Finally press <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: This works fine for me. To spell it out for non-english os versions: alt- View - Navigation - navigation area

Answer (score 1):

Using Autohotkey to assign F8 as panel alternator, this is what has worked for me:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
~F8::
RegRead, NavigationPane_Status, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\Sizer, PageSpaceControlSizer
If NavigationPane_Status = a700000001000000000000000a050000
RegWrite, REG_BINARY, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\Sizer, PageSpaceControlSizer, a00000000000000000000000ec030000
Else
RegWrite, REG_BINARY, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\Sizer, PageSpaceControlSizer, a700000001000000000000000a050000
WinGetClass, eh_Class,A
If (eh_Class = “#32770” OR A_OSVersion = “WIN_VISTA”)
Send, {F5}
Else PostMessage, 0x111, 28931,,, A
Send, !{Up}
Send, {Backspace}
Return
#IfWinActive
```

By compiling this this file into an executable and using one of these several programs that add to the explorer toolbars with configurable buttons, you can use this script as a one-click hot button. In the same way, with the other panels, Preview and Details, respectively assigning Alt+P and Alt+Shift+P.

Answer (score 0):

After you hide Navigation Pane as you did go to (I'm translating this from spanish, don't know exact words in english)

Tools > Folder Options > See > Apply to all folders

Next time you open a window it won't show the Navigation Pane