# Keyboard shortcut to resize Navigator / Organize panel in Explorer

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

Is there a keyboard shortcut to resize the Navigator/ Organize panel in Windows Explorer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut to hide/show Explorer navigation](http://superuser.com/questions/41979/keyboard-shortcut-to-hide-show-explorer-navigation)

Comment: @techie007 Resizing is not the same as hiding/showing if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, I'm pretty certain the answer is no.

As you can see by the link in the comments of your OP, there is a way to turn it on and off with (a long winded) keyboard short cut but, there is no option with Windows alone to resize the navigation pane (nor do I know of any third party tool to do it).